# How to map AJAX JSON to Label & Value?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, ajax

I have the current function which uses AJAX. It retrieves a JSON list of objects correctly. Each object has an ID & a Name. I'm unsure how to map each object ID to the Value and each name to the Label so that when a user chooses an option, I can actually process the selection.

```
$(function() {
    var nameArray = [];

    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source : function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url : "controller",
                type : "GET",
                data : {
                    term : request.term
                },
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(data) {
                    $.each(data,function(key,val){
                        nameArray.push(val.Name);
                    });

                    response(nameArray);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

At the moment I just read the names in to an array and send that through the response to be used in the JQuery-UI autocomplete. However I need a way to send both val.Name & val.ID.

This is so that I can later use 'ui.item.label' and 'ui.item.value' within a select:function.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to push an object to the array that has the properties you want.

```
success : function(data) {
          var nameArray = [];
          $.each(data,function(key,val){
                nameArray.push({value:val.Name, label:val.Name, id: val.id});
           });

           response(nameArray);
}
```

You could also simplify this a little bit using `Array.prototype.map()`

```
var nameArray = data.map(function(item){
    return {value: item.Name, label: item.Name, id: item.id};
});
```

Comment: had wrong property `name` ...fiexed just now with `value`

Answer (score 0):

Use

> JSON.parse(data)

inside your success function to parse the results into an object. From there you'll access its attributes as you would on any object.

Comment: This is already done internally by `$.ajax` when dataType is set and will throw errors since `data` isn't a string